# Rspec make sure we ended up at correct path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

Is there a way we can test that we ended up at the expected path with rspec?

Something like:

```
it "should be the forgot password path" do
  response.should redirect_to(new_user_password_path)
end
```

This gives me an error:

```
 Failure/Error: response.should redirect_to(new_user_password_path)
 ArgumentError:
   @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem once, and it was because the capybara visit method doesn't set the @requests variable, the one that rails use to do the redirection assertion (the should redirect_to calls the rails assert_redirected_to).

It's sad, but you have to test it differently, like checking the page's content, for instance.

Comment: Bummer.  Did you mean "It's sad"?