# Test Redirection with RSpec and Capybara (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I just have learnt how cool RSpec and Cabybara is, and now working around it to learn writing actual test.

I am trying to check if after clicking a link, there is a redirection to a specific page.
Below is the scenario

```
1) I have a page /projects/list
        - I have an anchor with html "Back" and it links to /projects/show

Below is the test i wrote in rspec

describe "Sample" do
  describe "GET /projects/list" do
    it "sample test" do
      visit "/projects/list"
      click_link "Back"
      assert_redirected_to "/projects/show" 
    end
  end
end
```

The test fails with a failure message like below

```
    Failure/Error: assert_redirected_to "/projects/show"
     ArgumentError:
       @request must be an ActionDispatch::Request
```

Please suggest me on how i should test the redirection and what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try `current_path.should == "/projects/show"`

Capybara also implements a `current_url` method for the fully qualified URL.

More info in the [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session:current_path).

**EDIT**

Capybara now has a RSpec matcher called have_current_path, which you can use like: `expect(page).to have_current_path(some_other_page_path)` (thanks @bjliu)

Comment: might be better to use `projects_path`? And maybe as well use the `expect` notation while you're at it

Comment: Capybara now has a RSpec matcher called `have_current_path`, which you can use like: `expect(page).to have_current_path(some_other_page_path)`

Answer (score 12):

Im not sure that this can be what you need, but in my tests I prefer such approach:

```
...
subject { page }
...
before do
    visit some_path_path
    # do anything else you need to be redirected
end
it "should redirect to some other page" do
    expect(page.current_path).to eq some_other_page_path
end
```

Comment: `page.current_path` is unnecessary, you could use just `current_path` since you already declared `page` as a subject

Answer (score 5):

From the [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Cucumber):

> In Rails when a rack application redirects (just like Warden/Devise redirects you to the login page), the response is not properly updated by the integration session. As consequence, the helper assert_redirected_to won’t work.

Also this page has the same information: [Rspec make sure we ended up at correct path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797509/rspec-make-sure-we-ended-up-at-correct-path)

So you'll need to test that you're now on that URL, rather than test that you are being redirected to it.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use the route, something like:

```
assert_redirected_to projects_path
```

rather than

```
assert_redirected_to "/projects/show"
```

Comment: When i use like `assert_redirected_to projects_path` it shows like `undefined local variable or method `projects_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x98b1c04>`